# Matrix Market into CRS conversion (sparse matrices)

Tags: math, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

When dealing with sparse matrices, how do I convert [Matrix Market format](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/formats.html#mtx) into CRS (Compressed Row Storage)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [BeBOP Sparse Matrix Converter](http://bebop.cs.berkeley.edu/smc/) source code? It's linked from the page you referenced.